# Meteor.Call strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I have the following code running on the server:

---

#### server/tickets.js

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {

    ticketsCollection = new Mongo.Collection('tickets');

    var tickets = ticketsCollection.find({}).observe({
        added: function(tkt) {
            Meteor.call('allocateTicket', tkt);
        }
    });
}
```

#### server/ticket_allocation.js

```
Meteor.methods({
    allocateTicket: function(ticket){
         console.log(ticket);
    }
});
```

---

At first when the server starts, i get the error:

> Exception in queued task: Error: Method not found [404]

however, the subsequent calls goes fine. Not sure why it does not recognise the Meteor Call function while starting the server.

Is there any method similar to this.ready() used in subscriptions.

Comment: why do you call methods on the server? wouldn't it be easier to directly call the function of the method?

Comment: also, to answer that question we need to see how these lines of code are laid out in your files. Is either of them in a `Meteor.startup` block? Otherwise the call will indeed happen before the method is defined.

Comment: Awesome @ChristianFritz, silly of me. Can you post your comment as answer so that it could be accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you don't try to execute the `call` before the method is actually defined. If you don't want to worry about loading order of files in your project (http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp; File Load Order), then the safest thing to accomplish this is to make the call inside a `Meteor.startup` block, for instance:

```
ticketsCollection = new Mongo.Collection('tickets');

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function() {
    var tickets = ticketsCollection.find({}).observe({
        added: function(tkt) {
            Meteor.call('allocateTicket', tkt);
        }
    });
  });
}
```

Then it doesn't matter in which file you define the method.